# separating date and time from datetime column in excel

Tags: excel

how to separate date and time from datetime column if you have the format as below :

click here to view image

[image]

I am trying int(datetime column) for fetching date ; Datetime column - int(datetime column) for fetching time column

Comment: Split out using Day(), Month(), Year(), Hour(), Minute() and second().

Answer (score 2):

Your formula cannot work because your data is a text string (note that it has a letter included) and not a number.

So first convert the string into a "real" time with:

```
=substitute(a2,"T"," ")
```

You can then use:

```
Date:  =INT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," "))
Time:  =MOD(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," "),1)
```

and be sure to format the results as desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your column is formatted true date then use to separate date

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

For time

```
=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")
```

If data is in text string or output by `TEXT()` function then try below functions.

```
for date =TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]"),"yyyy-mm-dd")
for time =TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),"hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

For date

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("T",A2)-1)
```

For time

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("T",A2))
```